# React component hook for only when props update (and not state)

Tags: reactjs, react-component

There is some behavior I want to kick off when and only when the props for my component have changed. In the past I have utilized `componentWillReceiveProps`, but with the [current documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) this seems to be deprecated. The docs seem to indicate that `componentDidUpdate` is the new recommendation, however this fires off on any update, including a change of state. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is also mentioned, but this is required to be a static method.

I could write some code to run through all of the `prevProps` and `this.props`, but that seems repetitive.

Comment: why do you want to not update when the state changes? that is one of the main functionality of "react". it "reacts" to state changes. stop setting the state then?

Comment: I'll need the state to change eventually, but I need to do other component-instance logic between receiving the props, and before updating the state. Since this logic is instance-specific, I don't think the static `getDerivedStateFromProps` can handle it. More detail in the comment to one of the answers.

Comment: i think you need to supply code that you actually tried and tell what you are expecting to happen. maybe use console.log to tell us when what should happen. otherwise nobody can help you and also the question is not of good quality.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I assume the correct approach would be to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update the state when the props have changed, and then have that state change trigger the behavior you want. 
 I can't think of a reason to avoid using state for updating the component, that's basically the essence of react.

Comment: The behavior I want to call is another instance method on the React component. `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a static method that can only update the state variables.

Let's say for instance, this is a component that loads its own data from an API, via a `this.loadInformation()` method. It is triggered from within the component, say after mounting, or when certain event handlers are triggered within or beneath the component. However I also want to support the parent component making changes, and needing to pass down a new prop to trigger a new information load on this component.

Comment: I see. Couldn't you have the child component state changed and then load the data inside the `componentDidUpdate` method?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is meant. I want to handle a case where the change is triggered by Parent Component, and the only way it can communicate is to change the props it passes down.

Comment: What I meant was: Pass a prop down (let's say a bool `shouldLoad`) >> have the state changed in the child component (again, let's say `shouldLoad`) inside the `getDerivedStateFromProps` if the state's `shouldLoad` is different than the props's >> check if `this.shouldLoad` is `true` inside the `componentDidUpdate` method, if so call `this.loadInformation()` and change `shouldLoa